# javafx access Image outside jar

Tags: image, javafx, jar, resources

I kind of struggle with accessing an image source outside my jar.
I am loading images for an canvas which has not been a problem when the image is located inside the jar.

But now I wanted to create a Folder outside the jar with the required images, because the client should change them later on.

The structure looks like this:

```
dir:
 -program.jar
 -images:
    -picture.png
 -saves:
    -config.cfg
```

I am confused as I can load the config by

```
String path = "./saves/config.cfg";
```

But when tryig to access the Image this way I get an invalid URL

Doing following as recommended by others doesn't seem to work aswell:

```
File f = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
String path = f.getParent() + "images/picture.png"
Image image = new Image(path);
```

Still a Invalid URL, this time with unknown protocol: c

Putting `"file:///" +` at the begining of path won't work aswell except no Exeption but also no Image.

Any ideas on how to correctly acces the image and maby general advice for working with resources outside the jar?

Comment: You need to absolute path to that file. i.e. `C:/path/to/your/file.png`

Comment: Sure but how will I be able to get the absolute path when it's not clear where the program is located (user could put the directory anywhere) That is what I tried to achieve

Comment: You will need the user to put the directory in a certain location if they want to use that file. Its fairly standard practice. You can even create the directory for them if it doesnt exist, and direct them there.

Comment: @HypnicJerk, that is not true and would be a horrible "standard practice" if it were. You would use a path relative to your main application path.

Comment: @Zephyr Hmm. I can see your point. So now his question would be how to get the main applications path and go from there?

Comment: I tried to acces it via relative path but as you can see it does not work properly. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Hypnic sure that's somehow part of my question the problem I have, the getClass().getProtectionDomain()......... and after this the .getParent() does the job and gives me the applications parent directory but when I add the rest of the path to the image and try to load it, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just use a relative path for the `File` object:

```
File imageFile = new File("images/picture.png")
```

Your `program.jar` will start in the base directory; when creating the `File` object, that is the starting point for the path you want to pass to the constructor. Therefore, `new File("images/picture.png")` will look for the pictures.png file in the "images" subdirectory.

Once you have the file, you'll want to create your `Image`  using that file's URI:

```
Image image = new Image(imageFile.toURI().toString());
```

That actually creates the full absolute path to the file.

> **Sample Application:**

Here is a quick example that you can try yourself. You'll need to make sure you have the `resources` folder created in your output folder (where the .jar file resides), as well as a suitable image file within it.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        // Just a box to put our image in
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Create our image. It is located in the "resources" folder of our application. We will first create a File
        // to represent the external resource.
        File imageFile = new File("resources/icon.png");
        Image image = new Image(imageFile.toURI().toString());

        // Add our image/ImageView to the scene
        root.getChildren().add(new ImageView(image));

        primaryStage.setTitle("External Images");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

This will work whether running the application within your IDE or after building the JAR or JavaFX application.